# Adding general custom field in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, field

I am currently working on a webpage that show a slider in the homepage. To know which posts it should display there, it looks for posts marked as "featured" (which is a custom field) and it show the X more recent (where X is a number I set in code).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'sfeatured',
        'value' => 'super-sfeatured',
        'compare' => '='
      )
    ),
    'orderby'=>'date',
    'order'=>'DESC'
  );
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I don't like having to change the amount of posts shown in the slider from the code (now the amount is 10, as you see). I would like to have a "general" custom field in my Wordpress admin page where I can set the number of slides I want to show.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Its better you add an meta_box

Comment: You could try that https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages
or try using ACF if you are using this plugin already

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use post custom field in the page.

create a custom field in homepage in admin and echo that field value in place of '10' in the array.

2. "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin, in case if you are using ACF plugin

Comment: Yes, I am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin, how could I achieve this? Could you be more specific?

Comment: add a field in acf section in admin panel and use it for homepage and call that field in homepage like this $value = get_field( "field_name" ); and use the $value in place of 10

Comment: the problem is that I don't have a page created for home, that page works differently... Could I add it to a different page and use it in home? Thank you for your time

Comment: then you need to call the page id, it will work, please check acf documentation for more info

Comment: I have added a new field called slides_number for a page with id=194. The field appears in admin panel in that page and I can modify it. In my view I do this:  $slides_number = the_field('slides_number', 194); but it doesn't get any value. What am I doing wrong? I have tried also with get_field

Answer (score 0):

Add screen option to Posts, So that you can modify number there

There is hook `add_screen_option` which is used to register custom meta boxes.

Sample code from Codex:

```
    add_action('wp_network_dashboard_setup', function() {
    add_screen_option('layout_columns', ['default' => 2]);
});
```

Comment: sorry, I'm afraid I'm not getting this. Where should I add the add_screen_option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bonzer Custom Fields Creator https://wordpress.org/plugins/bonzer-custom-fields/ for creating field in any of the settings pages

i.e. 
     Settings > General 
     Settings > Writing 
     Settings > Reading etc.

and avoid spoiling your posts with field that is only needed for homepage